# Converting from 24 hour time to 12 hour time and vice versa C++

Tags: c++

I have this homework question that asks the following

Write a program to convert the time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation and vice versa. Your program must be menu driven, giving the user the choice of converting the time between the two notations.

Furthermore, your program must contain at least the following functions:

a function to convert the time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation

a function to convert the time from 12-hour notation to 24-hour notation

a function to display the choices

function(s) to get the input

and function(s) to display the results.
(For 12-hour time notation, your program must display AM or PM.)

**The problem I am facing is getting the seconds to display correctly and also allowing the user to input AM or PM.**

Here is the code I have already created:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;
void getInfo(int&,int&,int&,bool&,bool);
void convert12To24(int,int,int,bool,int&,int&,int&);
void convert24To12(int,int,int,bool&,int&,int&,int&);
void printTime(int,int,int,bool=false,bool=false);
void showOptions();
int main(){
    cout << "============================================\n";
    cout << "              :: Information ::             \n";
    cout << "This program  enables the  user to  convert\n";
    cout << "from the 12-hour notation to the 24-hour no-\n";
    cout << "tation, and vice versa.\n";
    cout << "============================================\n";


    int c; 

    int h12;

    int m12;
    int s12;

    bool isAM;

    int h24;

    int m24;
    int s24;

    do{

        showOptions();
        cout <<"--------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Your choice: ";
        cin  >> c;
        cout <<"============================================\n";

        if(c == 1){


           getInfo(h12,m12,s12,isAM,true);


            cout<<"--------------------------------------------"
                    <<"\n";


            convert12To24(h12,m12,s12,isAM,h24,m24,s12);


            printTime(h24,m24,s24);

         } else if (c == 2){

            getInfo(h24,m24,s24,isAM,false);
            cout<<"--------------------------------------------"<<"\n";

            convert24To12(h24,m24,s24,isAM,h12,m12,s12);


            printTime(h12,m12,s12,isAM,true);

        } else {

            cout << "Invalid option.\n";
        }
        cout <<"============================================\n";
    }while(c != 'x' && c != 'X');



    return 0;
}


void getInfo(int& h,int& m,int& s,bool& isAM, bool is12H){                    
    int maxH;

    int minH;


    char response;

    h = 1;
    m = 1;
    s = 1;


    if(is12H){

        maxH = 12;
        minH = 1;
    } else {

        maxH = 24;
        minH = 0;
    }


    cout << "Please, enter the below  values, and  notice\n";
    cout << "that no value could be negative.\n";

    do{
        if(h < minH || h > maxH){
            cout<<"--------------------------------------------"<< std::endl;
            cout << "Hours must have the range from ["<< minH <<"-"<< maxH <<"].\n";
        }
        cout << "    Hour: ";
        cin  >> h;
    }while(h < minH || h > maxH);


    if(h == 24){

         m = 0;
     } else {
        do{
            if(m < 0 || m>59){
                cout<<"----------------------------------------"<< "----\n";
                cout <<"Minutes must have the range from [0-59]"<<".\n";
                }
            cout << " Minutes: ";
            cin  >> m;
        }while(m < 0 || m>59);
        do{
            if(s < 0 || s>59){
                cout<<"----------------------------------------"<< "----\n";
                cout <<"Seconds must have the range from [0-59]"<<".\n";
                }
            cout << " Seconds: ";
            cin  >> s;
        }while(s < 0 || s>59);
    }

    if(is12H){
        cout <<"Press AM if this is AM, other values for PM\n";
        cout << "Response: ";
        cin  >> response;

        if(response == 'a' || response == 'A'){
            isAM = true;
        } else {
            isAM = false;
        }
    }
}


void convert12To24(int h12,int m12,int s12,bool isAM, 
                       int& h,int& m,int& s){           

    if(isAM){

        h = h12 % 12;
        m = m12;
        s = s12;
    } else {

        h = 12 + h12 % 12;
        m = m12;
        s = s12;
    }
}


void convert24To12(int h24,int m24,int s24,bool& isAM,
                       int& h,int& m,int& s){           

    h = h24 % 12;

    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }

    m = m24;
    s = s24;


    if(h24 >= 12){
        isAM = false;
    } else {
        isAM = true;
    }
}


void printTime(int h,int m,int s,bool isAM,
                   bool is12H){                  
    cout << fixed << setfill('0');

    if(is12H && isAM){

        cout << "The time is: " << setw(2) << h << ":" << setw(2) 
                 << m << ":" << setw(2) << s << " AM\n";
    } else if (is12H && !isAM){

        cout <<"The time is: " << setw(2) << h << ":" << setw(2) 
                 << m << ":" << setw(2) << s << " PM\n";
    } else {

        cout << "The time is: " << setw(2) << h << ":" << setw(2) 
                 << m << ":" << setw(2) << s << std::endl;
    }
}


void showOptions(){
    cout << "                :: Options ::               \n";
    cout << "[1] convert from 12-hour to 24-hour notation\n";
    cout << "[2] convert from 24-hour to 12-hour notation\n";

}
```

Here is the sample input provided:

```
1
8
30
20
AM
99
```

I also do not understand why they have that 99 in the sample input. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try using a string to capture am/pm and then check which string they entered.

Comment: We won't be able to tell you why they have 99 in the sample input. That's a question for them, or you might have missed it in the problem.